# Inserting elements of a vector into a tree in random order

Tags: random, vector, scheme

I am trying to insert elements from a vector in random order into a tree. My logic was to set the elements of a copy of the vector to be false and then check this vector each time to see if all of the elements are false. Otherwise, continue looping until all of the elements from the vector have been inserted. My problem is that when I use "vector-set!" it changes the value of both "vec" and "vec1". Why is this?

```
(define (vector-check vec)
(define (vector-check-h i)
  (if (= i (vector-length vec)) 
      #t
      (if (eq? (vector-ref vec i) #f)
          (vector-check-h (+ i 1))
          #f)
      ))
(vector-check-h 0))

(define (insert-r vec)
  (define (insert-h vec1 T)
  (let ((r (random (vector-length vec))))
  (cond ((eq? (vector-check vec1) #t) T)
        ((eq? (vector-ref vec1 r) #f)
         (insert-h vec1 T))
        (else 
         (begin
         (vector-set! vec1 r #f)
         (insert-h vec1 (insert (vector-ref vec r) T))
         )))))
(insert-h vec '()))
```

By the way, I know this program has no practical purposed because of the way binary search trees work, it is just for practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vec1` is aliased to `vec`, which is why changing the contents of one affects the other. But if you change the initial `insert-h` call to use `(insert-h (vector-copy vec) '())` instead, it will dealias the two, since `vec1` will then be a fresh copy.